# I can't understand an numpy array concept in sklearn

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

my code

```
diabetes_x=np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

diabetes_x_train=diabetes_x
diabetes_x_test=diabetes_x

diabetes_y_train=np.array([3,2,4])
diabetes_y_test=np.array([3,2,4])

model=linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(diabetes_x_train,diabetes_y_train)

diabetes_y_predict=model.predict(diabetes_x_test)

print("Mean Squared error is :",mean_squared_error(diabetes_y_test,diabetes_y_predict))

print("weights : ",model.coef_)
print("intercept : ",model.intercept_)
```

in this code we are taking diabetes_x value in 2-D but in diabetes_y_train and test why we are taking 1-D array. Can someone please explain me both of the concept of diabetes_x and _y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In machine learning terminology X is regarded as the input variable and y is regarded as output variable.

Suppose there is dataset with 5 columns where the last column is the result. So the input will consist of all the column except the last and the last column will be used to check if the mapping is correct after training or during validation to calculate the error.